# Exception:org.json.JSONException: Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject in android

Tags: android, json

API Response:

```
{
  "Response": {
    "message": "Success",
    "url": "http://makemyreport.com/MobileApps/",
    "cor": "DEMO",
    "headerMsg": "DEMO",
    "subheadMsg": "DEMO"
  }
}
```

Asynctask code:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject responseObj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("Response");
message = responseObj.getString("message");
String url = responseObj.getString("url");
orgId = responseObj.getString("cor");
orgName = responseObj.getString("headerMsg");
String subheadMsg = responseObj.getString("subheadMsg");
```

log cat error:

```
Exception: org.json.JSONException: Value  of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect that is the not the current code or expected JSON.

Comment: Your code looks like it should be working.

Comment: no issue in your code

Comment: If you guys thinks this code is perfect, then why it is throwing this exception?

Comment: Did you check the content of `response`, which is used in `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);`

Comment: Hi guys , I got my exact issues. Actually what happened , the content of 'json response' was sending some special character before curly brace. I just removed that string part, now it's working fine. Thank to all for your kind attention & support.

Answer (score 1):

Implement it in `try catch` block also check your response string if it has expected value:

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONObject responseObj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("Response");
    message = responseObj.getString("message");
    String url = responseObj.getString("url");
    orgId = responseObj.getString("cor");
    orgName = responseObj.getString("headerMsg");
    String subheadMsg = responseObj.getString("subheadMsg");

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();              
}
```